# Strange behavior of "Assigned to" field in TFS 2012

Tags: tfs, agile

When I create a bug on TFS 2012 and somebody marks it as resolved and check the code in (typing the item id), the field "Assigned to" gets my name instead of the developer's name (who did fix the bug).

Why does this happen?

Using TFS 2012, Agile template (no modifications)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you opened the bug, the default workflows assign the bug back to you to verify and close it once it has been resolved.

If you need a report with the person who marked the bug as resolved (usually the developer on check in) you can use the "Resolved By" column from "Column Options" dialog of the TFS Query.[image: TFS 2010]

Comment: Wow! I just saw I needed to close it.

Comment: Resolved just means "fixed", or "invalid", or "won't fix". Usually, the expectation is that you then get the build with the fix, and make sure that it is actually fixed (i.e. that the dev fixed the right thing, or fixed it completely), and then close it.

Comment: If I close it, the assigned to will get the developers name or will it be blank?

Comment: If you are using VS as your interface to TFS, you can open the item, change the state to closed, and see what it does to the fields. It won't affect the item until you save it. IIRC, usually, it clears the assigned to field.

Comment: So this is only a temporary field that only gets a value between states so the person can easily see what he has to do. Right?

Comment: I don't know if i'd call it temporary, it is always there (including versioning, you can query against "ever assigned to"), and you can technically assign closed items to someone, but it doesn't make much sense. But yeah, it's purpose is to help users know where they need to act on items.